# How to recover data from ubuntu after switching from windows 10?

Tags: data-recovery

After switching Ubuntu, i surprisingly get to know that my previous files from the whole drive deleted. Now how I can recover my data from the Filesystem partition. I didn't try anything yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files) FYI, overwritten data is unrecoverable

Comment: If you installed Windows where Ubuntu was then it deleted everything and because most if not all was actually overwritten there's no chance to recover anything. Next time do your backups before.

Comment: And because you no longer have Ubuntu, also disagreeing with previous commenters, your question is off-topic here.

Comment: I am not clear if you switched from Windows to Ubuntu or from Ubuntu to Windows?